# How to fix the error when trying to bring up first-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am working with Hyperledger Fabric 1.3.0. I get the following error when I execute the "byfn.sh -m up" in the fabric-samples/first-network.

Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] Y
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.3.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.3.0
Error: No such container: cli
ERROR !!!! Test failed

Please help

I don't have docker-compose.yaml but what I do have is docker-compose-cli.yaml. The contents are below:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:`enter code here`
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems you are having some issues with your versions, what I recommend is to clean all the containers and images of docker running:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q) //for images

docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) //for containers
```

After that, re-download the fabric samples, I think that they updated the 1.3.0 stable version yesterday, **setup again your crytogen path** (this is very important if you are pointing to an old version of the **cryptogen tool** it won't work!

And give a try again, if that don't work, I recommend you to give us more information like.

Where are you running your First-Network? Windows? Mac? Linux?
Version of Linux? Version of docker?

If you are still having troubles you can check out my guide of how yo setup an hyperledger fabric from scratch using the Basic-Network example, it's kinda easy and explain all the concepts that you need.

[Setup Hyperledger Fabric in multiple physical machines](https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4)

**Update**

Since you are in Windows, don't use your users Folder, create a simple folder structure like **C:/HLF** for example.

After that in your **.env** file add this line `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`.
This helps docker to understand the windows paths, cause they are different in linux.

**Update #2**

Let's try another solution then, go to your **script.sh** inside your **script folder**, look for the command `peer channel create...` and add this line just before the **IF** statement where are them `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`

Review the Windows Extras section in the fabric solution, check that you have all installed.

[Hyperledger Fabric - Windows Extras](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/prereqs.html#windows-extras)

After that re generate everything. Run the docker commands in my first answer and add this.

```
docker network prune
```

After that.

```
./byfn.sh down
./byfn.sh generate
./byfn.sh -m up
```

**Update #3**

I tested the **fisrt-network** using Windows 10 and Docker for windows (Using linux containers) with the configurations I mentioned before and it's working fine.

My docker version is: **18.06.1-ce**

And I followed the Fabric Hyperledger official tutorial: [Build Network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/build_network.html)

The only difference that I saw it's that I ran `./byfn.sh up` instead of `./byfn.sh -m up`

I recommend you to reinstall your docker for windows, maybe its something corrupted, that doesn't allow you to start a your network.

Hope that it helps!

Comment: I did as you suggested by removing all the images. I did not have any containers running. Still I am having the same problem. I am running on Windows 10 in WLS (Windows Linux Subsystem) using Docker version 18.06.1-ce

Comment: I did as you suggested by adding to the .env file. My folder structure is c:\workspace\fabric-samples\first-network. I am still having the same problem

Comment: Could you add you docker-compose.yaml to your question?

Comment: I don't have docker-compose.yaml but what I do have is docker-compose-cli.yaml. I have added it to my question

Comment: It still does not work. I still get the same error. If some body can get it to work on Windows 10 please let me know. I have spent 2 days and can't get it to work. I have given up. I am going to get myself a Mac.

Comment: Okay I found my problem. docker-composer was not set up correctly which resulted in the cli container not being created. Hence the error "No such container: cli". After I re-installed docker-composer everything ran fine.